# Should I implement PriorityQueue (Heap) on List in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I understand that `priorityQueue` is perfect on `Array` as its nature is in place.

**Should I implement PriorityQueue (Heap) on List in OCaml?**

If I do it on `List`, then I have to remove the `in-place` thing and think a way to `every time` create a new list in every step. So I am wondering whether it is worth it, or not.

---

Actually, I have a more deeper thought on this.

So, many `fundamental` algorithms / datastructures were invented from `in-place` (I use `invented` because I understand many in-place can be transformed to be `not-in-place`).

However, `FL` does not recommend `mutable` things. One of my further questions is **how do I choose between `in-place / mutable` and `immutable`?** or **in OCaml, when should I choose between `list` and `array`?**

---

For example, in the above `priorityqueue` case, if I was asked to write a `priorityqueue` in OCaml, should I prefer `array` as it is more nature and easier, or I should choose list for the sake of being immutable?

Comment: If you are curious and willing to experiment, search for fibonacci heaps. These let you implement mutable priority queues using a circular linked list of trees. I wrote one implementation to try it out, and modified it to be immutable, albeit with a small theorical performance impact. Binary heaps are the standard way though, and you can surely find a good explanation in the usual places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using immutable data gives surpising benefits in modularity and reliability. In essence, it becomes impossible for data to become corrupted through modification by other modules. Modules no longer need to worry about other modules, and who "owns" the data. You don't realize how onerous this is until you don't have to do it any longer. Another unexpected benefit is that it becomes much easier to reason about the behavior of your code, because it acts like a mathematical function. I have experienced both of these in practice, and this has made me an FP believer. The cost is generally surprisingly modest, either a smallish constant factor or maybe an extra *log n*.

Another advantage of immutable data is persistence, i.e., the ability to maintain historical states of the data with no extra effort. (It's interesting to implement an *undo* operation in an immutable environment.)

That said, I sometimes do use mutable data, because it can be faster.

As a meta-comment, I'd suggest you spend some time using only immutable data in OCaml. It makes a very interesting puzzle initially, if nothing else. After some direct experience you'll be in a position to judge where the tradeoffs lie in particular cases. So I'd suggest you try implementing an immutable priority queue (or read how others have done it).

Comment: Ok, I agree with you about the good things of immutable. I am just wondering, say, if a interviewer ask me `write a priorityqueue in OCaml, should I prefer array as it is more nature and easier, or I should choose list for the sake of being immutable?` How should I answer?

Comment: Or is it worthy to implement a priorityqueue using list and using the original/standard algorithm?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to skip past the learning part and jump straight to the answers for a job interview! The reason they ask is that they want to hear what you've learned. You could try both and see how they behave. My general answer is that I'd use the immutable data unless I had a good reason not to. If somebody is hiring an OCaml programmer, they're probably interested in whether they're familiar with immutable data. But I'm just one guy with a certain kind of experience.

Comment: could you please tell should I implement heap using List and also using the original binary heap algorithm (which is best for in-place array)?

Comment: I would say you should do both, yes, though it's hard to imagine why you would want to know my opinion about it! :-) If you don't want to work out the immutable case from scratch, I'd look at Okasaki's priority queue implementations. They're not that complicated looking.

Comment: could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187445/how-should-i-organise-my-ocaml-project ?

Comment: (I'm not a good one to ask this question. I use vi + make for all of my OCaml work! You *can* set things up however you like with make....)

Comment: After struggling for half day, I have to say, implementing heap using List in ocaml is difficult, but I will continue

Comment: could you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260430/how-to-implement-a-binary-heap-using-list-in-ocaml?

Answer (score 2):

Batteries has an efficient functional heap over here: http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatHeap.html with find_min being O(1) and all the other heap operations are log(n)

I believe the implementation is a standard binomial heap as described in Okasaki. Take a look here: https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batHeap.ml

If you still insist on a heap with destructive operations however, then I think core has an implementation ripped off .NET. You would have to a close look.

More importantly, I agree with Jeffrey and suggest that you get really comfortable with functional data structures first and only use imperative ones when you absolutely have to. I'm sure this has been suggested to you before, but the best source for this kind of information is Okasaki's purely functional data structures book. I cannot recommend it highly enough.

Answer (score 2):

Binary heap (the implementation of priority queue you are probably thinking of) is typically implemented on a *dynamic* array (called "vector" in some languages), i.e. one that you can add elements to or remove elements from. `array` is not suitable because it is fixed-sized; its size is fixed when you create it. You could first implement a dynamic array structure on top of `array`, and then implement binary heap on top of that, if you are up to it.

Another option for priority queue is to use a self-balancing binary search tree; the OCaml standard libarary already has several data structures using self-balancing binary search tree -- `Set` and `Map`, and they are implemented as immutable, functional data structures. Self-balancing binary search tree offers the same time complexity as binary heap for most operations (remove min element and add element; which are O(log n) for both structures). It's less efficient for peaking the min element (O(1) for binary heap; O(log n) for tree), but that is usually not used by itself anyway. One issue with using `Set` is that it disallows duplicate elements; ideally you would want a "multiset", but OCaml doesn't have one in the standard library; if you don't care about duplicate elements, then this is not an issue.

I would not recommend using `list` for this.

Comment: ok, I will try implement it using list. but should I implement the list based heap using the original algorithm (in-place binary heap)?