# How should I organise my OCaml project?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I know this question is quite general and I even don't know how to better ask.

---

I don't have much experiences in `C` and I just wish I can do similar thing in OCaml as in Java.

For example, in `Java`, I normally create a project (using `Eclipse` or other IDE), then I have a `src` folder and a `bin` folder. All `compiled` stuff go to `bin`.

---

**So for the starter, how could I do something as simple as above? just split the source files and compile files easily?**

---

Normally, how do you guys organise OCaml project files?

---

The final question is that should I use `mli` or `module`? I noticed that `ocaml-batteries-included` is using `mli` a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's plenty of differing opinion about this subject in the OCaml community and it really depends on how structure or flexibility do you want. Myself I use a makefile and ocamlbuild if I'm being lazy and [oasis](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/) for everything else. You should check out a few random OCaml projects to see how it works and what you would like. For example an oasis project might look like so: https://github.com/avsm/ocaml-github. You only need to look at the _oasis file (think of it like pom.xml if you ever used maven). Running `oasis setup` should generate all of the build files for you. `ocaml setup.ml -all` followed by `ocaml setup.ml -install` would install the library on your system.

As for using mli's. There's a tiny bit of controversy regarding them. Here's a discussion from the mailing lists: http://www.mentby.com/Group/caml-list/why-should-i-use-mli-files.html

My own opinion is that they are optional unless your modules are part of a public API that others will use. In which case they are mandatory.

Answer (score 7):

Nice question !
I will be really interested in seeing other answers, but here is how I organize my projects:

First of all, I use Eclipse with the excellent [OCalIDE](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/), it's a really cool eclipse plugin, actively maintained.
If you are an Emacs user, you can use [TypeRex](http://www.typerex.org/index.html) (which is dead, but as the OCaml community move very slowly you have all your time).
If you are a Vim user, there is always Omlet but there isn't any really nice solution.

With Eclipse, you can choose "Managed Ocaml Project" which means basically *I don't want to worry about compiling stuff and I will never share this project*.
Start with that, that's good enough for personal projects and temporary tests. But if you can't you will have to choose between "Ocaml Makefile Project" and "Ocaml project with ocamlbuild". Choose Makefile, it's far more flexible and easy solution.

Eclipse will provide you [a default Makefile for Ocaml projects](https://bitbucket.org/mmottl/ocaml-makefile/), very well explained in the comments. I recommend you to use it if you are not familiar with the Ocaml build system. If you are, I recommend you to use your own Makefile because the default one is too huge and unreadable (I think).

---

Great ! Now we have our project in our favorite editor and are ready to put a global structure !

At the root of the project, I follow the convention of a classic GNU tarball, that said:

```
/
|- src/     # source files
|- lib/     # dependencies
|- test/    # tests files and test binaries
|- _build/  # binaries and object files, sometimes managed by ocamlbuild
|- AUTHORS  # who did that marvelous stuff
|- README   # what is it 
|- Makefile # *always* provide a Makefile, you never know...
|- _tags    # when I use ocamlbuild
|- _oasis   # when I use oasis
```

Sometimes, there is no lib directory, that's good. But you should provide a AUTHOR and README file because it's quiet positive for your project.

---

That was the boring part, what about the src directory ?

1. OCaml Modular system is very helpful in making things in their own containers. I note in my own experience that:

   - I don't use internal modules for anything but functors
   - I keep my modules consistent by themselves (sort of golden rule). For that my modules name are mostly related to datatypes or specific containers with internal states (what javaists call Singletons)
   - I often make two or three obviously specific modules: the entry point, the module that contains all common types, and the module that contains all commonly used functions. It avoid circular dependency.
2. I keep all flat in the `src/` directory unless I can really see a structure in my modules (those are parsing, those are AI computing, those are network...). The same way I do with C projects.

   OCaml is a concise language so you should have few files. As for C projects, try too keep your directory architecture as flat as possible, remember that directory aren't part of module name or namespace, so it's only to programmers convenience !
3. The mli part: it really depends of the goal of your project. This is my methodology :

   - the only general rule is: document the mli if it exists. Mlis are here to help compilers **and** programmers.
   - Is it for you ? Document in the ml part and generate only mli for typing constraints or too-large-to-browse ml.
   - You want to distribute your project ? Document in the mli because that the first file we will read if we have the choice. Choose the files you will generate interfaces, maybe some are internals and you don't want them to be read by casual users.
   - They are always needed when you deal with the OCaml object system as it can become messy very quick.

In the general case I'm happy to keep my mli as few as possible so a guest will immediately know which files are good to know and which are internals/advanced.

Moreover it helps for refactoring because I don't have type constraints that stops me going ahead.
Keep in mind that the test suite is here to make sure we don't broke anything (see [OUnit](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/ounit/), your distro should have packaged one for you. It's very simple and efficient, good project).

That's all I see. Hope that will help anyone !